# UX Writing : "Enter the user's name" vs "Enter user's name"

Tags: placeholder

one quick question, as a placeholder. "Enter the user's name" or "Enter user's name" ? Why ?

Comment: Could you add some context?

Answer (score 2):

Out of those two specific options: **Enter the user's name**

Why? Because if you are going to use the word "Enter" in either case, you might as well go for the more grammatically correct option.

---

However, both options sound like you are expecting somebody to enter the name of a user that isn't themselves. If you expect a person to enter their own name, then you should change the wording. For example:

Enter *your* user name.

Also, are you expecting a "username" to be entered, or a full name? If the latter, then your current text is a bit too ambiguous. I would advise something more specific, like:

*Enter the full name of the user*

---

General advice: Try to stick with what people are used to seeing...

Username, First Name, Full Name, etc.

If you want to be more descriptive of the type of data:

- Enter a unique username.
- Enter the first name of the user.
- Enter the full name of the user.

Comment: Yeah, I'm expecting someone to enter the name of an already existing user/client. Guess the best way would be to go with "Enter the name of the user/client". Thanks.